# SSIS 2012 incremental load for 200-300 tables

Tags: ssis

My project started 2 months ago, and already I'm transferring over 100 tables on each process I run to the Data Warehouse.

I'll probably reach 200-300 tables pretty soon and do not believe my current development approach will scale.

I still have 3 weeks' versions (product dev sprints), and tables are still changing their structure (data types, column names, new columns etc) which gives me a real headache, so I ignored it for the first few weeks.

How did I ignore it?

1. Truncated all the tables before i take them to the ODS (Operational Data Store)/MRR layer
2. Took all the data from the source system fully to the MRR layer
3. Created only the dimensions "incremental" table (which still changes every week with new columns and changed data types)
4. Dynamically creating and populating the staging tables and the warehouse tables.

Now my model has started to form, so I have to take care of the incremental loads

1. It seems easy since I have updatetime for each record, but I also have deletions in my source system, how can I approach this ?
2. I've considered CDC, but this will be time consuming as I have to put it table by table
3. Any solutions for someone who starts with 100-200 tables?

Comment: How does the Agile approach allow for fundamental design changes? because that's what you're faced with here - a lot of back end development which has no visibility to users. I've never seen this addressed in the Agile projects that I've seen.

Answer (score 0):

I follow a style similar to your "ignore it" design for as long as possible. Full refresh keeps your design agile and can go as fast as 1 million rows per minute.

When this eventually runs out of legs, and there are deletions in the source system, I delete all my data back for a date range (e.g. 3 months) as agreed with the data experts.  You may have to break that delete into chunks e.g. day by day.  I also try to fully refresh such data e.g. each weekend (as often the data experts are misinformed).

Comment: Thanks Mike, 

unfortunatly , since this is OEM , we can't have the actual "data experts" to approve any misinformed data. 
and the system analysts always want to hold the stick on both end , to have everything always on and always updated "as possible" (without allowing anything as "impossible"  if you know what i mean .. ) 
 :) 
i think i'll have to go CDC for the deletions , i whish someone would create this automation that does the ODS layer for me ..   much simpler, but i guess i'd have to pay him ....   :)

thanks again